# toast when phone is plugged for charging using BroadCast Receiver but not working

Tags: broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I had done an simple app which display some text when the phone is plugged for charging. But its not working on my HTC One X. The below is the code, can any one help?

```
public class ChargingBroadcastReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        String POWER_CONNECTED = "android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED";
        if (i.getAction().equals(POWER_CONNECTED)) 
        {           
            Toast.makeText(c, "Thanks For the Power", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you set the required uses-permission in android manifest?

and try to use `yorclassname.this` for the context!